# Reducir ancho de la columna a grafica

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

estoy utilizando chart en un form en c#, donde he podido generar una grafica de ejemplo pero esta grafica me muestra las  columnas bien pegadas
como en la imagen adjunta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces cree una serie llamada xxx que en este caso es la del medio y le he puesto de color Transparent, pero esto hace que tenga un espacio mas grande y yo solo deseo que se separe lo minimo.
Este es mi código

```
        string ult12meses = "Últimos\n12 meses";
        string ult3anios = "Últimos\n3 años";
        string ult5anios = "Últimos\n5 años";
        string ult10anios = "Últimos\n10 años";

        double MesesAcumulado12Meses = 4.000000000;
        double MesesAnualizado12Meses = 4.000000 ;
        double MesesAcumulado3Anios = 4.000000;
        double MesesAnualizado3Anios = 1.31594038201;
        double MesesAcumulado5Anios = 4.0680047936;
        double MesesAnualizado5Anios = 0.8006762384;
        double MesesAcumulado10Anios = 4.0339968401815751;
        double MesesAnualizado10Anios = 0;

        Color colorSerie1 = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#005d8c");
        Color colorSerie2 = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#6da5c8");

        

        chart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 300);
        chart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("area"));
        
        this.Controls.Add(chart);
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0}%";

        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;

        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        
        Series series1 = new Series("1");
        series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        series1.Color = colorSerie1;
        
        series1.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        series1.Points.AddXY(ult12meses, MesesAcumulado12Meses);
        series1.Points.AddXY(ult3anios, MesesAcumulado3Anios);
        series1.Points.AddXY(ult5anios, MesesAcumulado5Anios);
        series1.Points.AddXY(ult10anios, MesesAcumulado10Anios);
       
        
        foreach (DataPoint point in series1.Points)
        {
            point.Label = point.YValues[0].ToString() + "%"; 
        }

        #region xxxx

        Series xxx = new Series("xxx");
        xxx[""] = "";
        xxx.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        xxx.Color = Color.Red;
        xxx.Points.AddXY(ult12meses, 1);
        xxx.Points.AddXY(ult3anios, Double.NaN);
        xxx.Points.AddXY(ult5anios, Double.NaN);
        xxx.Points.AddXY(ult10anios, Double.NaN);

        #endregion

        Series series2 = new Series("2");
        series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        series2.Color = colorSerie2;
        
        series2.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        series2.Points.AddXY(ult12meses, MesesAnualizado12Meses);
        series2.Points.AddXY(ult3anios, MesesAnualizado3Anios);
        series2.Points.AddXY(ult5anios, MesesAnualizado5Anios);
        series2.Points.AddXY(ult10anios, MesesAnualizado10Anios);

        foreach (DataPoint point in series2.Points)
        {
            point.Label = point.YValues[0].ToString() + "%";
        }

        series1["PointWidth"] = "0.4";
        xxx["PointWidth"] = "0.2";
        series2["PointWidth"] = "0.4";

        chart.Series.Add(series1);
        chart.Series.Add(xxx);
        chart.Series.Add(series2);
```

y el resultado me sale así. (el color rojo lo puse para diferenciar el porque no disminuye el ancho si agregue el )

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y como resultado final seria así,con el espacio que separa y un border minimo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que librería para los gráficos estas utilizando ?? Esto es winforms??